# Assembler nasm displaying all divisors of provided number

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have to write programm that displays all divisors of provided number. Number is read from keyboard and stored in `bufor` but simply my program doesn't work well and I am stuck in black point with it... After running it I `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` maybye someone more expirienced might help with it. All suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance.

```
_start:             ;


;*******reading from keyboard

mov rax, 0 ; kyboard descriptior
mov rdx, 10 ; bytes to read
mov rdi,0 ; keyboard reading
mov rsi, bufor ; 
syscall; function call

;********loop for*************************  
    mov rax, [bufor] ;
    mov rcx, 1
    mov rcx, 2      ; ECX is i=10
for_loop:
    cmp     rcx, [bufor]        
    jae     loop_end    ; go into, when i >= edi

    xor rdx,rdx ; to avoid div errors
    mov rax, [bufor]   ;

    div rcx         ; 

    push rbp ; push function pointer to stack
    mov  rbp, rsp; store stack pointer
    push rcx ; push counter pointer to stack
    cmp  rdx, 0
    je   display

    inc  rcx                ; i++
    jmp  for_loop

loop_end:
        jmp exit


display: 
    mov  rax, 1     ; fun number

    mov rdi, 1      
    mov rsi, rcx    ; 
    mov rdx, 5      ; 
    syscall
        jmp done

done:
    pop rcx ; getcounter 
    pop rbp ;get function pointer
    ret             ; return


;*********exit from program*******
exit:
   mov rax, 60
   syscall




section .data           ; 

section .bss
     bufor       resb 5           ; bufor 5 bytes
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even assemble due to missing symbols `koniec_petli` and `wyjscie`. Besides, learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.

Comment: I made changes and improve question.

Comment: For starters, the user will probably enter the number as text, but your program makes no effort to convert it.